# Formatting date in YYYYMM format in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am getting a date as a String from a table below in the format:

```
2014-09-02
```

which is YYYY-MM-DD format.

The query is:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE CODE = 'MYDATE'
```

I want to modify above query so that the result is:

```
201402
```

I tried this, but not getting in correct format:

```
select char(year(date(value))) || char(month(date(value))) from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE CODE = 'MYDATE'
```

The result is coming as:

```
 1            
------------ 
2014       9
```

I have db2 9.5 with me.

Comment: If it's already a string, why bother converting it to `DATE` if you can just use `SUBSTR()`? Anyway, try adding `TRIM()` around both `CHAR()` calls.

Comment: The value you are getting appears to represent September 2nd, 2014.  The one you say you want appears to represent February 2014.  Are you sure about this?

Comment: You haven't selected an answer, did you find a solution find this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're **actually** getting a `DATE` data type (and even if you're not, in the ISO format you have there, DB2 should be smart enough to convert it automatically), then you can use the [`VARCHAR_FORMAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-179) scalar function:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(VALUE, 'YYYYMM')
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
WHERE CODE = 'MYDATE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your strings are going to be in the exact same format, why not just remove the dashes with REPLACE() and then grab a substring, like so:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE(VALUE,'-',''),1,6) FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE CODE='MY DATE'
```

Also, as Dan said, in your example you only selected the year and day, but I'm assuming from your code that you want the year and month.